# Show multiple data from an Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I want to show the best 5 scores from each different Game I have. So I made this function :

```
public function records (){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $games = $em->getRepository(Game::class)->findAll();

    foreach($games as $g){
        $records = new ArrayCollection;
        $records = $em->getRepository(Game::class)->findAllRecords($g->getId());
    }


    return $this->render('game/records.html.twig', [            
        'games' => $games,
        'records' => $records,
    ]);
}
```

Here is the repository function :

```
public function findAllRecords($id){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('g');

    $qb->select('g.name')
        ->innerJoin('g.Parties', 'p')
        ->innerJoin('p.playeds', 'y')
        ->innerJoin('y.joueur', 'j')
        ->addSelect('y.score')        
        ->addSelect('j.nom, j.prenom')
        ->where('g.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)            
        ->orderBy('y.score', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults('5');
    var_dump($qb->getDQL());
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

And finally the view :

```
{% for g in games %}
{{ g.name }}
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>                
            <th>score</th>
        </tr>
            {% for r in records %}
       <tr>
            <td>{{ r.score }}</td>
        </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

It doesn't completely works as I just get the data from the last game ID. How can I show the data for each game ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach($games as $g){
   $records = new ArrayCollection;
   $records = $em->getRepository(Game::class)->findAllRecords($g->getId());
}`

Here's your issue. This is always overwriting. You want to do something like:

```
$records = new ArrayCollection;
foreach($games as $g) {
  $records[] = $em->......;
}
```

That should solve your issue

Comment: Hi, almost worked. I get "Key "score" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4" does not exist.". I suppose I have to loop inside the correct "records" index now. Something like this : {% for r in records[0] %}. But how do I replace 0 with the indexloop of the game for ?

Comment: you should be able to do {% for r in records[loop.index] %} that should give you the index of the games loop. i dont know what loop.index means in the next loop though. But this should work for your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it give me an error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined index: loop").

Comment: I managed to do it setting an attribute with index.loop inside the gameloop : {% set i = loop.index0 %} and then use this in my second loop : {% for r in records[i] %}